# JUNG get all target vertex labels from the Cluster

Tags: java, graph, jung

at the moment, I'm searching for a possibility to get all targets Vertex labels of one cluster. I'm using the radial layout and i know the  function's getEdgeTargets and getEdgeSource. But How can i find all targets Vertex labels in multiple clusters.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    { // check the last added cluster the edge count. Because edge count = Nodes Count
        if(cluster.graph.containsEdge(cluster.graph.getEdge(nodesList.get(nodesList.size()-1).getNodename() ,cluster.graph.getEdgeTarget(i)))&&
            Nodecnt <   cluster.graph.getEdge(nodesList.get(nodesList.size()-1).getNodename() ,cluster.graph.getEdgeTarget(i)))
        {
            Nodecnt = cluster.graph.getEdge(nodesList.get(nodesList.size()-1).getNodename() ,cluster.graph.getEdgeTarget(i));

        }
    }
```

Comment: What clusters are you referring to?  Please provide more context.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaO'Madadhain, i found an approach for my problem. But at the moment i got the exception. Because i don't know max count of the vertexes or edges.

Comment: After every restart of my example. The Cluster or the max count of vertexes and edges can be different. In my case i need a found like graph.size or graph.length

Comment: Hi @JoshuaO'Madadhain, i found in the last 5min a solution max count edges. graph.edgeSet().size()   I will check my approach and come back.

Comment: You need to phrase your questions in a way that helps people understand the problem that you're trying to solve.  Providing a code example can help, but only if the code is actually connected to what you're doing.  In this case:
(a) you don't explain what you mean by a cluster
(b) you don't explain why you need the cluster size
(c) you don't describe the exception you're getting, or what appears to be triggering it
As it is, you're not really getting help because your problem is unclear.
I recommend checking out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking further questions.